# using the trigger framework for before update

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I am using the [SFDC trigger framework](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework) to force a particular field of the Order Object to be always the same. for example, if the the user enters on the field Status 'Active' I want to automatically change it to 'draft'. My code as follows:

Trigger handler:

```
public class OrderTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {
    public override void beforeUpdate() {
        for (Order o : (List<Order>) Trigger.new) {
            o.Status = 'dralf';
        }
    }

}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order (before insert) {
    new OrderTriggerHandler().run();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This, to me, seems like it would be more appropriate as a validation rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing `before update` in `trigger OrderTrigger on Order (before insert)`.

Also technically you should compare with old list as well that if old record contains status=='active' then only you change its value to 'draft'. In this it will always change it to draft.

If you want to run similar logic on insert then you need to create a separate method for beforeCreate as well according to this pattern.

Comment: if I want that Status is always 'draft' then like that is ok. Right?

Comment: Move this logic to a method and then call it from the other events as well.

Comment: @Cubancoffee No, this code would only run on insert and not on update, and your case is to run it on update. so you need to pass `before update `.